# Facing Unknown SSL error oracle 11g after Adding certificates in oracle wallet

Tags: ssl, plsql, oracle-wallet

> I want to call API so that I can integrate SMS gateway in my
>   application for that purpose the steps will be
>
> 1. Get the certificates
> 2. Create a wallet
> 3. Add certificates to wallet
> 4. Create ACL.

Certificates have been added to the wallet. Below command is verifying about the saved certificates.

```
  F:\cert>orapki wallet display -wallet F:/cert
        Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
        Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

        Requested Certificates:
        User Certificates:
        Trusted Certificates:
        Subject:        CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
        Subject:        CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.
```

Created the ACL.

```
BEGIN
        DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('www.xml', 'WWW ACL', 'SCOTT', TRUE, 'connect');
        DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE('www.xml', 'SCOTT', TRUE, 'resolve');

        -- All
        DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('www.xml', '*');
    END;

    commit;
```

The procedure I am using for HTTP connection along with wallet

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_SESSION_ID (url VARCHAR2) AS 

request UTL_HTTP.REQ;
response UTL_HTTP.RESP;

    BEGIN
    UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:F:/cert', 'mypassword');

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(url);
       UTL_HTTP.SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_CHECK(FALSE);
        request := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url, 'GET');
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(request, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
        response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(request);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HTTP response status code: ' || response.status_code);
    END GET_SESSION_ID;
```

but getting the error

**Error report -
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-28857: Unknown SSL error
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.GET_SESSION_ID", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 9
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.**

Please help!

Comment: Looks like the first step is detailed in the error message.... '*Action: Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.'  First step is to do a dbms_output of this and get some more information

Comment: @ShaunPeterson  **dbms_output.put_line( ' OTHER Error Msg  : ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlcode  || Utl_Http.Get_Detailed_Sqlerrm); ** got output **OTHER Error Msg  : -28857ORA-28857: Unknown SSL error**